# What photo editing software to run on slow netbook laptop?

Tags: windows, photoshop

I am going to travel, packing with me a 1015PX Asus netbook.

Is there any software for photo editing that I could use on it? Basic contrast, cropping and RAW conversion is desired.
I already installed correct raw codecs.. Perhaps an old version of Photoshop?

Hardware specs:

- Intel atom N550 (1.66GHZ dual core, 64 bit capable)
- 2GB Ram
- 5400 RPM HDD - 256GB
- Windows 7 basic - 32 BIT

I can only upgrade the OS (64bit) and the harddrive (SSD). If any of these would make it possible, I could consider the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [GIMP](//gimp.org) is out of the question, and that leaves two contenders from my point of view:

### [Paint.NET](//www.getpaint.net/index.html)

> Paint.NET is free image and photo editing software for PCs that run Windows. It features an intuitive and innovative user interface with support for layers, unlimited undo, special effects, and a wide variety of useful and powerful tools. An active and growing online community provides friendly help, tutorials, and plugins.
>
> It started development as an undergraduate college senior design project mentored by Microsoft, and is currently being maintained by some of the alumni that originally worked on it. Originally intended as a free replacement for the Microsoft Paint software that comes with Windows, it has grown into a powerful yet simple image and photo editor tool.

### [FastStone](//www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm)

> FastStone Image Viewer is a fast, stable, user-friendly image browser, converter and editor. It has a nice array of features that include image viewing, management, comparison, red-eye removal, emailing, resizing, cropping, retouching and color adjustments. Its innovative but intuitive full-screen mode provides quick access to EXIF information, thumbnail browser and major functionalities via hidden toolbars that pop up when your mouse touches one of the four edges of the screen.

Which one is the easier on system resources is anyones guess. I would try them out both, and see which one fancies you the most.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its very useful! Why is GIMP out of the question?

Comment: @RoyB, I do believe GIMP require a lot more resources than the other two. But do feel free to try it, and see if it runs without bugging down the computer. For all of these programs I would suggest looking at system resource right after startup and after loading a picture or two.

Comment: Just saw this question in my history, I have used faststone to my satisfaction during my travels! Thanks a lot.